# How do you hide or archive a note in Evernote?

Tags: windows, evernote

Is there a way to hid a note or archive it so that it isn't "in my face" in Evernote?

I have some reference notes, that I don't need to see all the time, but I still want them accessible via Evernote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No there is no simple built-in function for this.

But there are multiple ways around it.

You could make a notebook 'Archive', where you move notes into.

OR

You could tag "archived" notes with a tag 'Archive' and then whenever you search, use "-tag:Archive".

**EDIT:**  If you want the contents of the note to not be visible in the 'Notes by'/'All Notes' section, then you can [encrypt them](http://www.evernote.com/about/kb/article/encrypt-note-content?lang=en).

Answer (score 2):

You can export them to mhtml or html, then delete them from your Evernote database.  Later you can open them in a browser, word processor, or have Evernote scan the folder to import them.  The nice thing about this solution is that you can still search them with Windows Search or any search utility.  Or you can zip them so they're not in your way.

The Export options are in the File menu, or by selecting your desired notes using the ctrl or shift keys in your list, then using your right-click menu to export.

MHT/Mhtml is the most complete format and will save the truest backup without messing too much with formatting and scripts.  But html opens up in many more programs, and is smaller.  Firefox can open mhtml if you get the "Mozilla Archive Format" extension.  (It can also associate your htm/html pages with Firefox so you never have to see IE again!)  :-)

Answer (score 2):

This would be a great feature. Of course you can always create a "Archive" or "Private notes" work-around. But it would be nice to have a "hide" feature so that notes could all be organized in your default structure, but not immediately visible to someone looking over your shoulder. I'll have to see if this has come up

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).